# testNG priorities & dependencies

Tags: java, testng

I'm having some issues with the priorities & dependencies on testNG. For example if I have this

```
@Test
public void login () { ... }

@Test (dependsOnMethods = {"login"})
public void method1 () { ... }

@Test (dependsOnMethods = {"method1"})
public void method2 () { ... }

@Test (dependsOnMethods = {"login"})
public void logout () { ... }
```

In this case it run like this :

login --> method1 --> logout --> method2

and this won't work since i'm not connected anymore

You gonna say to me just say that logout depends on method2 and everything will work ...

Yes it will ... but when method1 or 2 will fail it will skip logout instead of doing it ... and that's not what I want.

Then you gonna say me ... in that case it's easy just run with priorities instead of dependencies .... yeah but what if method1 fail ... then method2 might be good but won't work since method1 fail so I will have a false negative.

Any idea on how to do it right ?

Answer (score 0):

You should use before/after methods to do it:

```
@BeforeClass
public void login () { ... }

@Test
public void method1 () { ... }

@Test(dependsOnMethods = {"method1"})
public void method2 () { ... }

@AfterClass(alwaysRun=true) // alwaysRun to run the after method even if a test fails
public void logout () { ... }
```

Comment: Hello, I'm already using Before & After class to open & close the driver and login/logout is not necessary something that has to run at the start or at the end it might just be launched at the middle if whole app doesn't necessary require to login :/

Comment: I don't understand your problem. If some test methods don't need to be connected, move them into a dedicated class without login/logout

Answer (score 0):

You can declare `logout` to depend on "method2" and to [always run](http://testng.org/javadocs/org/testng/annotations/Test.html#alwaysRun--):

> #### alwaysRun
>
> `public abstract boolean alwaysRun`
>
> If set to true, this test method will always be run even if it depends on a method that failed. This attribute will be ignored if this test doesn't depend on any method or group.
>
> **Default:**
>
> `false`

Example:

```java
@Test
public void login () { ... }

@Test (dependsOnMethods = {"login"})
public void method1 () { ... }

@Test (dependsOnMethods = {"method1"})
public void method2 () { ... }

@Test (dependsOnMethods = {"method2"}, alwaysRun = true)
public void logout () { ... }
```

Comment: the issue with that is that logout does not depend on method2 so even if you make it like this it will run even if login failed

Answer (score 0):

You can define your method as :

```
        @Test(priority=1)
public void login()
{
    System.out.println("login");
}

@Test(priority=2)
public void method1()
{
    System.out.println("Method1");
    Assert.assertEquals("Method1", "login", "invalid msg not verified"); // Here test is failing as the expected value is not matching the actual value
    System.out.println("Verified");
}

@Test(priority=3)
public void method2()
{
    System.out.println("Method2");
    Assert.assertEquals("Method2", "Method2", "invalid msg not verified"); // Method1 fails however method2 is executed as actual and expected value are matching.
    System.out.println("Verified");
}

@Test(priority=4)
public void logout()
{
    System.out.println("logout");
}
```

This will help you to execute all the tests having priority as 1 and then only it will moves towards the test with priority 2 and then to 3 and then 4. I have added "Assert" to the above code which will help you to progress further in case any of the test is failing.

Comment: Hello, This won't work. TestNG will always call the higher dependency methods at first so it will still run login method1 logout method 2. you can use priority to say inside a same dependency which test should start first but that's it :/

Comment: Hi, I have set the prioritiy as 1 which will execute all the tests which are present in the priority 1(as per the dependencies) and then it will go to the priority 2. Hence it will execute login->method1->method2->logout

Comment: Did you run it ? Because i did and it still run logout before method2 due to the fact that logout depens on login and method2 depends on method1. And in the run process login is runing before method1 so it runs login all the method linked to him then move to the others

Comment: Hi, Sorry for my earlier code. It was not working as per the exceptions. I have edited my code now and I think this will be able to resolve your query. I have added "Assert" here which will help you to progress further even one of the method will fail. Please let me know whether this is working for you or not.

Comment: You're new version runs logout event if login failed

Comment: I don't think so as I have not inserted assert in login and logout. Even you want to modify more then make login and logout enabled as true.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110903/discussion-between-anubhav-mishra-and-user3718160).

Answer (score 0):

I believe when the question is nicely brainstormed at the same time few concepts have been ignored during implementation. Hope this provides a solution to the problem :

```
@Test
public void login () { ... }

@Test (dependsOnMethods = {"login"}, groups = { "afterLogin" })
public void method1 () { ... }

@Test (dependsOnMethods = {"method1"}, groups = { "afterLogin" }, priority = 1) 
public void method2 () { ... }
// you mark dependsOnMethods when it actually "depends on" something prior to its execution and 
// hence corresponds to the failure of method it is depending on

@Test (dependsOnMethods = {"login"}, priority = 2)
public void logout () { ... }
```

This would ensure the sequence as 
login --> method1 --> method2 --> logout

where,

*Case 1* : if `login` fails, methods dependent on it **shouldn't** be executed.

*Case 2* : if method 1 or 2 fails it wouldn't skip `logout` test

*Case 3* : if method 1 and 2 are not dependent on login, you can actually execute them with priority lesser/higher/equal making sure `they are all independent`.

Comment: @Julien Herr : correct me if the concept behind dependsOnMethods is  understood incorrectly by me.

Comment: the issue with this solution is that the fact that method2 depends en method1 make it so it will run this test after the ones that have the same depencies as method1 (so the ones that depends on login) and so make it fail because method2 will run after logout

Comment: @user3718160  edited the priority, now I hope it shouldn't be a concern

Comment: priorities are run after dependsOnMethods so it won't change anything :/

Comment: @user3718160 : to avoid that I hope we can mark the method 1 and 2 in same `group`.

Comment: I tried `group` didn't change anything :/ I think groups are only used for `dependOnGroups` and logout should not depend on anything else than login :/

Answer (score 0):

May be this can help

```
@Test (priority=1)
public void login()
{   
    System.out.println("login");
}

@Test(priority=2,dependsOnMethods={"login"})
public void method1()
{

    System.out.println("method1");
}

@Test(priority=3,dependsOnMethods={"method1"})
public void method2()
{

    System.out.println("method2");
}

@Test(priority=4,dependsOnMethods={"login"})
public void logout()
{

    System.out.println("logout");
}
```